# Bad rendering - fixed by resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have started to see some unusual rendering on our webpages where text is garbled and badly rendered, a screen resize always fixes it. It seems to effect both chrome and firefox.

I am not sure where to begin with this problem as I have never come across something like it before. What can cause this issue and how can it be fixed?

[image]

[image]

my text
                        `renders badly`

Comment: Use <div class = "container"> before mentioning any text.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: thanks it is in a container already though, fyi this is the page the screen shot was taken from - https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the 'weird' formatting of the name  LATEX?

Comment: @Daan I don't think so as we see it in normal pages, that bibtex is just normal text. Thanks though.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that those words are, in fact, wrapped in `<code>` elements.

Comment: Take a look with firefox at the applied CSS, open the debug console or use firebug. Post your css, for example, have you done a master reset?